# Assign 0 if the value is null or empty in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary

I want to use a ternary operator for the below jQuery statement like if employee_salary is `empty` or `null`, I want to assign as 0 (zero). Otherwise, just assign the actual value.

```
jQuery('#employee_form #employee_salary').val(parseInt(selected_table_data['employee_salary']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var employee_salary = selected_table_data['employee_salary'];
var salary_form_value = employeeSalary ? parseInt(employee_salary) : '0';
jQuery('#employee_form #employee_salary').val(salary_form_value);

// If you want to inline it, you could do the following:

jQuery('#employee_form #employee_salary').val(
  selected_table_data['employee_salary']
    ? parseInt(selected_table_data['employee_salary']
    : 0
);
```

Here is an example

```js
const s1 = null;
console.log(s1 ? s1 : 'There was a null value');

const s2 = ''
console.log(s2 ? s2 : 'There was an empty string');

const s3 = 'value';
console.log(s3 ? s3 : 'There was no value');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ternary` operator simply.

```
selected_table_data['employee_salary']
  ? parseInt(selected_table_data['employee_salary'])
  : 0
```

```js
console.log('' || 0);
console.log(null || 0);
console.log(undefined || 0);
```

Comment: you don't check for null ? i want to assign as 0 if there is null or empty value.

Comment: It will check `null`, `undefined`, or `empty`. Try to `console.log(null || 0);`

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work. i am getting as "NaN" if i use your solution.

Comment: Then this means you are containing different letters except those null and empty. Can you share `selected_table_data['employee_salary']` content for `NaN` cases?

Comment: The problem is the use of parseInt(thing) if thing is null/undefined.  Your answer doesn't match your examples.

Answer (score 1):

Using || operator or just a simple ternary operator would work if its `null`, `undefined` or `''`. But it won't work for a blank space like this one `'  '` (since `Boolean (' ')` evaluates as true) which it's not good if you want to replace any empty string or blank spaces for zero. So I would suggest you to do something like this,

`jQuery('#employee_form #employee_salary').val(parseInt(selected_table_data['employee_salary']) ? parseInt(selected_table_data['employee_salary']) : 0);`

This will allow you not only check if null, undefined, empty string and white spaces but also will prevent `NaN` to be a value on your form (instead zero will take place).

Comment: i have tried your solution but still i am sending the employee salary value as "NaN"

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that parseInt was your attempt to make this work yourself (fair enough).  I'm going to suggest you remove it and try simply

```
jQuery('#employee_form #employee_salary').val(selected_table_data['employee_salary'] || 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for you.

```
jQuery('#employee_form #employee_salary').val(selected_table_data['employee_salary'] * 1)
```